# Does every Lantern Color have its own language like the Indigo Lanterns?

Tags: dc, languages, green-lantern, dc-rebirth

I was reading volume 2 of *Green Lanterns* (DC Rebirth [the series about Jessica Cruz and Simon Baz]) and noticed that, when he was in compassion mode (the spoiler is just the antagonist of the arc, just want to be cautious that this great series isn't spoiled for anyone),

> Phantom Lantern

spoke in

> "...the language of the Indigo Lanterns" — Cosmic Cotton

Based on that, I would think that the Red Lanterns, Orange Lanterns, Yellow Lanterns, etc. would likely all have their own languages. However, I was just thinking that they might not all have their own languages and could maybe just use normal ones, because the alien Green Lanterns appearing at the end of the volume spoke in English to Jessica and Simon, without any special formatting or editors notes suggesting it was something else or translated by their rings. Therefore, my question is:
**Does each color of Lantern have its own language**?

Comment: I always assumed every Lantern speaks their native tongue all the time. Their rings translate anything anyway...

Comment: Odd that they didn’t translate the Indigo Lantern language

Comment: Indigo-1 is one of the few that happens to speak English, I think. It may have to do with the brainwashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We consistently see interactions between lanterns (whether they're of the same corps or different ones) that are printed as spoken English - that is to say, the rings are translating all of their alien languages such that they can be understood. Given that that doesn't apply to the Indigo language, it suggests that they're unique in that regard - the other Lantern Corps do not have a specific language.

It should be noted that the Indigo rings operate differently across the board (spoilers for *Green Lantern Vol. 5 (2011) - The Revenge of Black Hand* follow)

> Rather than selecting wielders that embody compassion, they select those without it, and enforce it upon them. It wouldn't be a stretch to assume that this brainwashing also imparts (and perhaps forces the use of) the Indigo language.